# Puppeteer sharp - how execute javascript function and return result

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I'm trying to do several tests with Puppeteer sharp but it's the first time that I work with it and I don't have very clear the syntax.

I have to open a page that I have on a server, and then run a javascript function (loadPageData('4', true)) that I have defined which can take about 15 minutes (on that page). When the function finishes, it fills a div tag on that page. I need that until the javascript function is executed and finished it does not pass to another instruction, but I do not know the syntax to use. Could you help me? what do I have to put in order to get the content of the div resultDIV?

Part of my code:

```
using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    await page.GoToAsync("http://.../mipagina.aspx");
    page.DefaultNavigationTimeout = 100000;
    try
    {
    string funcionEjecutar = "loadPageData('4', true)";
    var res = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync(funcionEjecutar);
    //works but no wait to finish execution of the function
    }
    catch(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `EvaluateExpressionAsync` resolves it means that the `loadPageData` returned some kind of value.
You could try using some `Wait` action after that.
For instance, [WaitForSelector](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_WaitForSelectorAsync_System_String_PuppeteerSharp_WaitForSelectorOptions_) in there is some selector that would tell you that the process finished. You could also use [WaitForFunction](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Page.html#PuppeteerSharp_Page_WaitForFunctionAsync_System_String_PuppeteerSharp_WaitForFunctionOptions_System_Object___)  passing a javascript function. In that case, the task will resolve when that function returns a truthy value.